# BOX API authentication get auth_code

Tags: python, api, oauth-2.0, python-requests, box

I am trying to interact with the BOX API.
I did multiple researches and I followed multiple tutorials on how to do it but I am missing a step...
I need to get the *auth_code* in order to get the *refresh_token* and the *access_token*. From what I understood the *auth_code* comes as a parameter in the url after the authentication.

```
from boxsdk import OAuth2
SDK = OAuth2(
    client_id=CLIENTID,
    client_secret=CLIENTSECRET
)
auth_url, csrf_token = SDK.get_authorization_url('{}/api/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={}&redirect_uri={}/folder/0'.format(ENPOINT, CLIENTID, ENPOINT))
TOKENS['auth_url'] = auth_url
TOKENS['csrf_token'] = csrf_token
requests.get(auth_url)
```

When I access by browser the url returned in *auth_url* it takes me to site like this:
[image].

And after I click manually in *Grant access to Box* it redirects me to the Box folder of my choice and the url is in the format: *https://xxxxx.com/folder/0?code=zzzzz&state=yyyyy*.
My goal is to extract the zzzzz and I do not understand how to get it programmatically...

```
References:
https://developer.box.com/guides/authentication/oauth2/with-sdk/
https://github.com/box/box-python-sdk#box-python-sdk
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ha26tN8amI0
```

A little help would be of great value, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

***Partial Answer:*** You retrieve the code by doing the following. Just redirect:

```
auth_url, csrf_token = oauth.get_authorization_url('https://google.com')
```

You have to set your Redirect URIs in the dev console to `https://google.com`. In the URL that you get back is the code that you need.

***Remaining Issue:*** The only problem is that you have to grant access manually. I still have to overcome that problem. Then would the problem be solved. Anyone have an idea how to grant access?